# How to remove grey lines from chakra-ui accordion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

There is a grey line on top and the bottom of my accordion, i prefer for it to be not there how do i remove the lines?
https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/accordion#styling-the-expanded-state
the accordion is here

I looked through the styles but no luck

Comment: `<AccordionItem borderColor="transparent">`

Answer (score 5):

Providing `border='none'` to `AccordionItem` will remove the top and bottom borders.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `borderColor`. Example:

```
<AccordionItem borderColor={"white"}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the css

```
.chakra-accordion .chakra-accordion__item:first-child {
    border-top-width: 0;
}

.chakra-accordion .chakra-accordion__item:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```